# Disable `ctrl+shift+w` shortcut in Firefox Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> shortcut because I sometimes press it accidentally when trying to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. Is there a simple way to disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do this with a Firefox add-on.  The one I have found in the past is Customizable Shortcuts.  [You can find it here.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts)  It gives you a new page in your Firefox options that allows you to reassign the shortcuts used for each command.  For example, I set the close window command that was `Ctrl+Shift+W` to be something I would never accidentally use, such as `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+9`.  It works pretty well on the Windows version of Firefox, although I admit I don't know about add-on cross compatibility with Linux.

Comment: At the moment (June 2015) the [version of the add-on up on addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) (version 0.6.2.1) doesn't work with Firefox 38. You can get the updated version (version 0.9.7) which does in [xpi form from the authors github repo](https://github.com/ttaubert/customizable-shortcuts/blob/master/customizable-shortcuts@timtaubert.de-0.9.7.xpi?raw=true).

Comment: As of July 2016 the author has discontinued the [Customizable Shortcuts add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts). The [Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) add-on described [here](http://superuser.com/a/1115417/57284) no longer works in Firefox (post Firefox 57 Quantum) due to [this missing functionality](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1320332) in Firefox. Additionally Firefox [doesn't have a built in facility](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303384) for changing keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Download and install [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), create a script called `ctrl_shift_w.ahk`

> #IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
>
> ^+w::
>
> return

Load the  script by double clicking it.

This will intercept the ctrl+shift+w key sequence.

Autohotkey is very small and installs in just a few seconds.

Comment: While I know and love autohotkey, I actually need something that works on linux. =)

Comment: Missed that in the title

Comment: @bryan If your answer was on topic, you'd need to add more to your script. Currently, it applies to the whole operating system. You'd want to use [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) to limit the hotkey to Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The confusingly named [Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) Firefox add-on supports customizing keyboard shortcuts. With this add-on you can disable the "Close Window" action associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

[image: Menu Wizard disabling Close Window]

The [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts) add-on mentioned in the answer from @techturtle was [discontinued by the author](https://github.com/ttaubert/customizable-shortcuts/commits/master) in July 2016 and Menu Wizard is a good replacement.

Note : Menu Wizard brings up a one time window after installation asking you to donate and asking if you'd like to install some malware so the author can get paid. Just click `No` twice and you should be good to go.

Comment: Just as a side note: "Not compatible with Firefox Quantum". I'm still looking for Quantum. BTW, upgrade to Quantum. I've personally made the switch from Chrome to FF after Quantum was launched.